# Как через css изменить цвет png изображения?

Tags: css, цвета

Есть png-иконки, например, из вк, синего цвета. Как с помощью css изменить его на белый?
P.S: нагуглил про `filter: hue-rotate()`, но с белым цветом это походу не вариант.

```html
<img src="https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png">
```

Comment: посмотрите здесь  http://fontello.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вы можете использовать css-фильтры:

- **grayscale** конвертирует цвета в ч/б
- **sepia** создает эффект сепии
- **saturate** задает насыщенность
- **hue-rotate** меняет цвета изображения в зависимости от заданного угла. Угол поворота определяет на сколько изменится данный цвет в цветовом круге от красного до фиолетового. Значение задается в градусах (0deg — 360deg)
- **invert** инвертирует цвета
- **opacity** задает прозрачность элемента
- **brightness** изменяет яркость изображения
- **contrast** изменяет контрастность изображения
- **blur** создает эффект размытости
- **drop-shadow** создает тень

**Примечание:** фильтры можно комбинировать между собой

```css
.bg{
  background-color: #8fbd35;
  padding: 20px;
  }

.fl{
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <img src="https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png">
</div>
<div class="bg">
  <img class="fl" src="https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png">
</div>
```

**Материал для прочтения**: [habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144852/)

**Демо:** [демо](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html)

Answer (score 11):

Если фон прозрачный, то можно выкрутить картинке [яркость](https://webref.ru/css/value/brightness). Например:

```
filter: brightness(10);
```

Но остаётся некоторая неуверенность, до какого же уровня выкручивать, чтобы наверняка исчезли все оттенки, кроме белого. А вот `brightness(0)` даст полностью чёрную картинку, которую легко [инвертировать](https://webref.ru/css/value/invert):

```
filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
```

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/dNKGXZ

```css
body { background: #ccc; }
img { display: block; }
```

```html
<img alt="" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/R8YjS.png">
<img alt="" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/R8YjS.png" style="filter: brightness(5);">
<img alt="" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/R8YjS.png" style="filter: brightness(10);">
<img alt="" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/R8YjS.png" style="filter: brightness(0) invert(1);">
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример смены цветов на CSS:

```css
@keyframes hue {
    from {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

.hue {
    animation: hue 10s infinite linear;
 }
```

```html
<img class="hue" src="https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png">
```

Comment: белый цвет так не получить

Comment: @VaskM в вашем случае используйте лучше иконочный шрифт. Цвета иконок можно менять через CSS.