# Как cделать svg из картинки, подключенной через background?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Я хочу изменять цвет `svg` картинки vk с помощью кода, имея только одну `svg` картинку.
Я хочу, чтобы по умолчанию картинка vk была темной, а при наведении становилась `#2a5885`.
Я не хочу иметь две картинки, только одну, чтобы можно было изменять цвет заливки этого `svg`, как это сделать?

```css
.footer__icons {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.footer__icons .vk {
  background-image: url('https://vk.com/images/svg_icons/ic_head_logo.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: 35px;
  background-size: 35px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #d2d1cf;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__icons">
 <div class="vk"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком варианте - никак, можно добавить SVG-код картинки напрямую в верстку и уже управлять, как захочется. Например:

```
.footer__icons .vk:hover svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

Comment: @Дмытрык я не понимаю как его применить, без `js`, так как он тут лишний слишком

Comment: да, спасибо, добавление svg в верстку, это самый подходящий вариант для меня, не додумался что-то сразу

Answer (score 2):

Я не понял в чем проблема, фон меняете и все, сама картинка - белая

```css
.footer__icons .vk {
  background-image: url('https://vk.com/images/svg_icons/ic_head_logo.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: 35px;
  background-color: #d2d1cf;
  
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s
}

.vk:hover{
  background-color: #2a5885;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__icons">
 <div class="vk"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я хотел заливку самой картинки изменять, оказалось, что самое легкое решение - это добавить весь svg в верстку, и там изменять цвет заливки

Comment: @МихаилКамахин вот еще посмотрите на это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/623347/188366